# Change Data Based on Radio Button

Tags: javascript

How do I do this in javascript where when a radio button is selected only certain fields show up to type in?? Please show work (preferably with JSFiddle) :)

```
    <form action="inc/add_p_c_validate.php" method="post"> 
    Professor<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Professor" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Course" /> 
    <br><br>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br> 
    Department: <select name="deptName"><option>Department 1</option> <option>Department 2</option></select>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `onclick` event of your `radiobuttons` to call a function that will check `radiobutton` status and then will show or hide elements of your form inside specified div elements.

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/S3PNM/2/)

```
<script language="javascript">
    function ChangeForm()
{
    if(document.getElementById('Professor').checked)
        document.getElementById('fieldset1').style.display = "inline";
    else
        document.getElementById('fieldset1').style.display = "none";


    if(document.getElementById('Course').checked)
        document.getElementById('fieldset2').style.display = "inline";
    else
        document.getElementById('fieldset2').style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<form action="inc/add_p_c_validate.php" method="post">
    Professor<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="ChangeForm()" id="Professor" name="addType" value="Professor" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="ChangeForm()" name="Course" id="Course" value="Course" />
    <br><br>
    <div id="fieldset1">Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
        Department: <select name="deptName"><option>Department 1</option> <option>Department 2</option></select></div>
    <div id="fieldset2">Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" /> </div>
</form>
```